# embedded insertion of Array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I have to try to store array data inside MongoDB using this query below. but every time I run this query its show success message without data means an empty array inside MongoDB,

my requirement is to store array data inside MongoDB as below query.

1). This is my node js script

```
this.childQuestionInfo = function(req, res, next){

    try{
        var quizArr = [];
        var quizObj = {
            'child.quiz.questionId' : req.params.questionId,
            'child.quiz.score' : req.params.score,
            'child.quiz.time' : new Date().toISOString()
            };
        quizArr.push(quizObj);
        var userObj = {
            'userid' : req.params.userId,
            'quiz' : quizArr
        };
        var childinfoSave = new QuizChildInfo(userObj);

        childinfoSave.save(function(err, data){
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.send("Child questionId score and date saved successfully" + data);
            console.log("Child questionId score and date saved successfully");
        });            
    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error While Saving the child questionId score and Date ' +err);
        return next(err);
        }
    };
```

2). This is my child schema

```
     userId:{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
            },
    quiz:[
          {
          questionId:{
                     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                    ref: 'question'
                                },
                                score:{type:Number},
                                time:{type:String}
                                }
                             ]
```

3). This is my output screen via postman

```
     "Child questionId score and date saved successfully
     { __v: 0,\n  _id: 57b9ac672c5791f8097d2132,\n  levelsAttempted: [],\n   quiz: [ { _id: 57b9ac672c5791f8097d2133 } ] }"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `$push`

```
this.childQuestionInfo = function(req, res, next){

    try{

        var queryObj={};
        var childObj={};
        var queryObj = {userid: req.params.userId};
        var options = {safe: true, upsert: true};
            childObj.questionId' : req.params.questionId,
            childObj.score' : req.params.score,
            childObj.time' : new Date().toISOString()
            };

        QuizChildInfo.findOneAndUpdate( queryObj, { $push: childObj }, options, function (err, data) {
            if(err) return next(err);
            res.send("Child questionId score and date saved successfully" + data);
            console.log("Child questionId score and date saved successfully");
        });


    }catch(err){
        console.log('Error While Saving the child questionId score and Date ' +err);
        return next(err);
        }
    };
```